# webservice data not coming using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, web-services

For some reason my web service data is not returning,

I created a web service that has a **[webMethod]** decorated method

```
[WebMethod]
public void sujestedProduct(string name)
{

    string strname = name.Substring(0, 4);
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(db.Products.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(strname)).ToList().Take(6)));

}
```

When I execute this method with parameter **cloth-wash** I got result as expected
[image]

but when I try to execute this **webservice** from web page using jquery ajax with same parameter **cloth-wash** then getting blank result like this

fig 1-

[image]

fig 2-

[image]

my jquery code is

```
var product_name = $("#name").text();
$.ajax({
    url: '/ProductService/CartClickNow.asmx/sujestedProduct',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'name': product_name },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#loader").css({ 'display': 'none' });
        var laptop_div = $('#sujested-product');
        laptop_div.empty();
        $(data).each(function (index, cart) {
            laptop_div.append('<div class="col-sm-2 select"> <div class="panel-body"><a href="/Product/' + cart.Name + '"><img src="' + cart.Image + '" class="img-responsive hvr-float-shadow hvr-shadow " alt="' + cart.productId + '"style=height:140px;width:150px;" />' + cart.Name + '</div></a> <div class="panel-footer"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' + cart.Price + '<span class="span-diccount-circle">' + cart.Discount + '%</span>off<span class="span-add-wish click-span glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty hvr-pus" title="Make Wish" id="' + cart.productId + '"></span></div>');
        });
    },
    error: function (data) {
        $("#loader").css({ 'display': 'none' });
        alert(Error);
    }
});
```

I don't know why data is not being returned.

Answer (score 0):

finally it work

```
   var product_name = $("#name").text();            
        $("#loader").css({ 'display': 'block' });
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ProductService/CartClickNow.asmx/sujestedProduct',  //sujestedProduct       
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'name': product_name },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loader").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                var laptop_div = $('#sujested-product');
                laptop_div.empty();
                $(data).each(function (index, cart) {
                    laptop_div.append('<div class="col-sm-2 select"> <div class="panel-body"><a href="/Product/' + cart.Name + '"><img src="' + cart.Image + '" class="img-responsive hvr-float-shadow hvr-shadow " alt="' + cart.productId + '"style=height:140px;width:150px;" />' + cart.Name + '</div></a> <div class="panel-footer"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' + cart.Price + '<span class="span-diccount-circle">' + cart.Discount + '%</span>off<span class="span-add-wish click-span glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty hvr-pus" title="Make Wish" id="' + cart.productId + '"></span></div>');
                });
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $("#loader").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                alert(Error);
            }
        })
```